# Programmatically accessing values R2 and datapoints in Google chart trendlines

Tags: google-visualization

I am currently working with Google charts trendline and want to access Values of R2 and datapoints through code.
Datapoints as in the datapoints used for creating trendlines.
is it possible?

Comment: sounds possible using [methods](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#methods) for `getHAxisValue` and `getVAxisValue`...

Comment: @WhiteHat -- would not getHAxisValue and getVAxisValue return me the data points of the graph and not the trendline? is there a way to specify whether I need the data points of Graph or Trendline?

Comment: those methods return the value of a certain coordinate, you could inspect the svg to find the coordinates of the trendline point you need...